# bash: variable increment does not occur

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem in one of my bash shell scripts. Asked a few colleagues, but they all just shake their heads (after some scratching), so I've come here for an answer.

According to my understanding it has to make new file after running loop every time if my

**lait**
and
**lait2**

variables are increasing or may be some position issue in my script
but my both variables not getting new value after executing each line it brings the old value and make the file with same name. 
Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
osdir=$(find /nodeFolder -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
lbdir=$(more /root/nodeFile.txt |wc -l)
lait2=1
l2=$(awk '{print $3}' < /root/nodeFile.txt | tail -$lait2 |head -1)
count=$(($lbdir-$osdir))
lait=1
newip=$(awk '{print $1}' < /root/nodeFile.txt | tail -$lait |head -1)
if [ $osdir -eq $lbdir ] ; then
   echo " Nothing to do "
else if [ $osdir -lt $lbdir ] ; then
   for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do
       cd /nodeFolder
       cp node-p-2.cfg   $l2.cfg
       sed -i 's/192.168.0.2/'$newip'/' $l2.cfg
       sed -i 's/node-p-2/'$l2'/' $l2.cfg
       echo " Node is added successfull"
       lait=$((lait + 1))
       lait2=$((lait2 + 1))
   done
fi
fi
```

my goal is to get new value when executing these lines

```
cp node-p-2.cfg   $l2.cfg
sed -i 's/192.168.0.2/'$newip'/' $l2.cfg
sed -i 's/node-p-2/'$l2'/' $l2.cfg
```

I have to make node files with their ips which are placed in /root/nodeFile.txt
I have to compare it with a directory /nodeFolder in which some files are already placed.
if the num of files placed in the directory is not equal to num of lines of /root/nodeFile.txt then it has to read /root/nodeFile.txt from bottom and take the input of node name and ip then make a file and make changes with respect to sample file node-p-2.cfg
my script is working but not updating two variables
lait and lait2 after executing loop.
Because I have to give input it from bottom and then second last line then 3rd last line then 4rth and so on.

Comment: It really isn't clear to me at all what your script is trying to do, and what you intend.  Can you spend some time adding some comments or something.  Or can include your trace output and explicitly point out exactly where the error is happening?

Comment: And, please learn to format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Now I have edited.

"
I have to give input it from bottom and then second last line then 3rd last line then 4rth and so on."

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `l1` and `newip` inside the for block if you want to update these values on each iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
osdir=$(find /nodeFolder -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
lbdir=$(more /root/nodeFile.txt |wc -l)
lait2=1
count=$(($lbdir-$osdir))
lait=1
if [ $osdir -eq $lbdir ] ; then
   echo " Nothing to do "
else if [ $osdir -lt $lbdir ] ; then
   for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do
       cd /nodeFolder
       l2=$(awk '{print $3}' < /root/nodeFile.txt | tail -$lait2 |head -1)
       newip=$(awk '{print $1}' < /root/nodeFile.txt | tail -$lait |head -1)
       cp node-p-2.cfg   $l2.cfg
       sed -i 's/192.168.0.2/'$newip'/' $l2.cfg
       sed -i 's/node-p-2/'$l2'/' $l2.cfg
       echo " Node is added successfull"
       lait=$((lait + 1))
       lait2=$((lait2 + 1))
   done
fi
fi
```

P.S.: Code isn't too readable, formatting is off, variable names are cryptic... these things don't help in spotting errors ;)

Comment: thats the point i am asking 
great work
its working
thankx